# Error message after successfully selenium login test to website

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

It's a simple selenium test to login in website. The test is passed if login with wrong username or password. But if you use your real's username and password test is fail, instead of that login is successfully. I believe that problem is in this code:

```
IWebElement ErrMessage = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("validation-summary-errors"));
```

How to avoid this error check after successfulled login? Here is all code:

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Logintest
{
    public class MyFirstTest
    {
        IWebDriver driver = new OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver();
        [Test]
        public void myFirstTest()
            {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://softuni.bg");
            driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Login")).Click();
            IWebElement userName = driver.FindElement(By.Name("username"));
            userName.Clear();
            userName.SendKeys("username");
            IWebElement userPass = driver.FindElement(By.Name("password"));
            userPass.Clear();
            userPass.SendKeys("password"); TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
            driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Ok")).Click();

            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/main/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/form/input[2]")).Submit(); TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
            IWebElement ErrMessage = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("validation-summary-errors"));
            Console.Write(ErrMessage.Text);
            Assert.IsTrue(ErrMessage.Text.Contains("Wrong username or password"));
            driver.Close();
            driver.Quit();
            }
    }
}
```

This is test fail error:
[image]

Comment: can you show the html please ?

Comment: How can you `login with wrong username or password` and `real's username and password test is fail`? Do you have a demo credentials for us?

Comment: I don't have demo credentials - using "username" and "password"

Comment: You code doesn't have any issue for invalid credentials. You are checking for existence of error message after valid login. please check your logic for valid login. You may need to check non existence of error message after valid login or existence of success login message.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do it, actually. I won't expected that first code which trying will be messed and with no help from lecturer

Comment: @locke Are you trying to validate the error message `Wrong username or password` for an invalid login?

Comment: @ DebanjanB , no, it makes some check after valid login. For invalid login it's working

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code for valid login,

```
public class MyFirstTest
    {
        IWebDriver driver = new OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver();
        [Test]
        public void myFirstTest()
            {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://softuni.bg");
            driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Login")).Click();
            //invalid scenario
            IWebElement userName = driver.FindElement(By.Name("username"));
            userName.Clear();
            userName.SendKeys("username");
            IWebElement userPass = driver.FindElement(By.Name("password"));
            userPass.Clear();
            userPass.SendKeys("password"); TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
            driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Ok")).Click();

            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/main/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/form/input[2]")).Submit(); TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
            IWebElement ErrMessage = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("validation-summary-errors"));
            Console.Write(ErrMessage.Text);
            Assert.IsTrue(ErrMessage.Text.Contains("Wrong username or password"));

            //valid secenario
            userName.Clear();
            userName.SendKeys("username");
            userPass.Clear();
            userPass.SendKeys("password");
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//form/input[2]")).Submit(); 
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
            int count = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("validation-summary-errors")).Count;
            Assert.IsTrue(count==0);
            driver.Close();
            driver.Quit();
         }
   }
```

Comment: Thanks, your code is working with correct username and pass. But with wrongs there's error - Message:   Expected: True  But was:  False. If I change Assert.IsTrue(count==0); to false it' upside down :)

Comment: update the answer with both invalid and valid scenario. try again and let me know.

Comment: Now it won't works, unfortunately. Thanks for help, anyway.